# How to create a TextSwitcher with Animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I wan to create a TextSwitcher with Animation Blink. 
When it fades the text should be changed. 
This is my Blink

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:duration="2000"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
 </set>
```

My Fragment which contains the TextSwitcher

```
private TextSwitcher Test ;

    public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        Test = (TextSwitcher)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TEST) ;

    Animation LeftSideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.blink);

    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.blink);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.blink);

    Test.setInAnimation(in);
    Test.setOutAnimation(out);



    return rootView;
}
```

My Fragment layout which has the part of the TextSwitcher I wrote it as the followings:

```
 <TextSwitcher
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TEST">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YES"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</TextSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.in);
Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.out);

switcher.setInAnimation(in);
switcher.setOutAnimation(out);
```

Comment: Indeed, I have made a Textswitcher in the layout with two textViews

Comment: What? The problem is you don't tell us what you have tried, you don't show any code, you don't say what exactly didn't work, how should we know how to help you then? And I am too tired to guess what you could mean with your no-info-sentences. Improve your question and somebody might have an answer.

Comment: You have to set a ViewFactory and override makeView(). Just like in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227552/animate-text-using-textswitcher-in-android .